# R-CNN for object detection in an image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

I am trying to solve a problem on object-recognition of the following image. The classes that I am particularly interested are: text, GUI elements with text, GUI elements without text, Figures.

From my recent literature read, it looks like R-CNN is one of the state-of-the arts in object detection? Is there a way to do this sort of object detection? [image]

Comment: Object Recognition/Classification and Object Detection are not the same, which one do you want exactly?

Comment: I am looking for object detection with more coordinate-specific.